# Remove chat program ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

what is chat program installed by default in ubuntu 12.04 that apears on top of ubuntu.
And how can I remove it ?

It's icon is like a white mail beside language selection bar.

Comment: Let me know what happened for further

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about empathy. Thats the chat program included in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get remove empathy
```

Comment: I removed it, but it's icon does not disappeared

Comment: Restart the system to apply the changes. Remember not only chat will associates with that Icon , your mail account(Thunderbird) also with that Icon only.

Answer (score 0):

The little envelop in the panel is the `indicator-messages` applet. You can remove it with

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages
```

But before you remove it, check if `apt` reports that some other packages depend on it, maybe you don't want to remove those.